# PySpark, pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition example does not work

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am running an Apache Spark Cluster within Azure Synapse and I'm currently checkin for a way to perform the same operation for each partition. To understand the spark function foreachPartition I started to execute the [example code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition.html).

However, the example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(14, "Tom"), (23, "Alice"), (16, "Bob")], ["age", "name"])

def func(itr):
    for person in itr:
        print(person.name)

df.foreachPartition(func)
```

does not output anything:
[image]

I thought it has something to do with the inner function and the print, so I tried to add it to a list and output the list at the end, but it's just empty.

[image]

Can someone explain why this is not working or where the actual problem is?

Spark Version is: 3.3.1.5.2-92314920

Comment: Your code works as expected for me locally, maybe print in databricks doesn't show to the output maybe try display,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running on a cluster stdout is the executors log's not the driver nodes.  Most notebooks take a redirect from the driver node's stdout, but not the executors.

You need to look at the executor logs from the Spark UI (no idea if Synapse has another ui for this) or instead of using foreachPartition, try using mapPartitions instead to return something to show on the driver node.

Comment: that was the problem, the function is executed by the workers and the stdout is not going back to coordinator. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***I also used and tried the same code and Iterating through the dataframe's records using PySpark's foreach() transformation produces no output. Instead of printing to the driver or your shell session, the records are printing to the Spark workers logs.***

**The workaround to this is use `toLocalIterator()` insted of `foreach()`**

**sample code:**

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(14, "Tom"), (23, "Alice"), (16, "Bob"),(16, "Fam")], ["age", "name"])

for person in df.toLocalIterator():
    print(person.name)
```

**Output:**

[image]